# How to mark JIRA attachments by using JIRA Python API

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I want to mark attachments that have already been downloaded to differentiate them with the one attached later on. Is it possible to set something like metadata of the attached files? Or any other ways?
PS: I should use JIRA python API

Comment: Can you give attachments different names when you download them?

Comment: I don't think you can tell from REST API if attachment was downloaded or not. And to rename attachment as mentioned by @m170897017 , you can download attachment and attach it again with modified name.

Comment: @m170897017 Renaming the attachments is an excellent solution. However, I'm not familiar with REST API, and didn't find a way to remove/rename the attachment. Do you know where I can find an simple example of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to modify the meta data from the JIRA REST API.

A solution would be to store the downloaded attachments ID's locally and then when downloading later exclude the attachments that are already present in your local list.

However if you wish to get into JIRA Plugin development you could look to create a plugin that creates a REST API that could modify the Attachments Meta Data and adds a `downloaded` property on the [`Attachment`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/attachment/Attachment.html) object. (Not 100% sure it is possible but could be)